# $z \in \mathbb{C}^-$ where $\mathbb{C}^- := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : Re(z) < 0\}$ identity

Tags: complex-numbers

Why is $|2-z|^2 = 4 + |z|^2 - 4Re(z)$,

where $z \in \mathbb{C}^-$ and $\mathbb{C}^- := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : Re(z) < 0\}$.

Why is this true?

Comment: What is $C^-$?....

Comment: the set of complex numbers z, where Re(z)<0

Comment: But your equality holds *always*, not just when $\operatorname{Re}z<0$.

Comment: Do not remove your question and replace it with a completely different one after it has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$|2-z|^2=(2-z)(2-\bar{z})$$

$$=4+z\bar{z}-2(z+\bar{z})$$
$$=4+|z|^2-2(x+iy+x-iy)$$

Answer (score 1):

This identity is true for any $z\in\mathbb C$

$|2-z|^2=(2-z)\overline{(2-z)}=(2-z)(2-\overline z)=4 + z\overline z - 2(z+\overline z)=4+|z|^2-4Re(z)$